# Simple C++ TCP/IP using streams (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, proxy, stream, netcat

What I need is a solution, that would let me (and my programming contest teamates) use TCP/IP in C++ under Windows in the simplest possible way. Some task will probably require a completely synchronous text communication with the server. The best option would be some DOS command or programme, that would redirect oll in/out communication of the application and send/receive it via TCP, like the Linux netcat:

```
> cool_proxy 123.122.121.43 1234 abc.exe
```

And inside the programme:

```
int query;
cin >> query;
cout << "The answer is " << (query+123);
```

However, Windows netcat seems to miss that feature... If this ain't possible, some other simple option could help:

```
Some_cool_sockect scs("123.122.121.42:1234");
scs.connect();
int query;
scs >> query;
scs << "The answer is " << (query+123);
```

It doesn't need to reach high performances; just simple, fully synchronous half-duplex TCP. I can handle TCP quite fluently in C#, so I could write some kind of a proxy, but maybe this thing already exists :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at a library like POCO. In the [namespace Poco::Net](http://pocoproject.org/docs/) there are several classes which allow you to create a client/server.

As this library is open source you can have a look at it and see how these classes create sockets etc.

Googling for "windows socket c++" also [brought this example](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/sockets.html): This will also give necessary basics, however I do not know if this example is up to date so it might not work with current Windows versions.